# run commands prior to click-once installation (not app launch)

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, publish

i want to execute "rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache" this commands just before installation process starts first thing i want it to do is execute above mentioned commands.

Basically it will clear app cache because some time during installation click once app will throw error "
Following errors were detected during this operation.
 * [6/7/2010 10:54:17 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Subscription)
  - Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity 
    is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version
    for this application or uninstall the preexisting application.
  - Source: System.Deployment"

A little more Google-fu resulted in an alternate call that would do the same thing on a computer without development sdks. And I know some day I'll need to remember this, so here it is: rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache

so i want to execute this command for safe side prior to every time user install this application (clickonce).